# How avoid to write the password in the configuration file of SVN?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, authentication, solaris, ldap

I am configuring the server SVN Collabnet (v1.5.6.1 for Solaris 10).
I succeeded to use the ldap server for SVN authentication.
How avoid to write a non encrypted password (XXXXX, here) in the following configuration file (collabnet_subversion_httpd.conf)?

```
ServerName mccuatsv10:8080
Listen 8080

User csvn

Group csvn

<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SetHandler svn
  SVNParentPath /appli/svn/repositories/
  AuthName "Subversion repository"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On
  AuthLDAPBindDN christian.desbordes@ibm.com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword XXXXX
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://eur.msd.world.ibm:389/OU=Users,OU=Accounts,OU=FR,DC=eur,DC=msd,DC=world,DC=socgen?sAM
AccountName?sub?(objectCategory=person)
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 6):

One option is to put the `AuthLDAPBindPassword` line in an appropriately chmodded file on its own, and use an `Include` in the apcahe config to pull that file in. i.e.:

```
<Location /svn>
   ...
   AuthLDAPBindDN christian.desbordes@ibm.com
   Include my_ldap_password.conf
   ...
</Location>
```

This keeps the password secure, while leaving the rest of the config world readable.

Comment: I strongly feel like there is a password file you can specify for LDAP auth, or am I remembering (incorrectly) the samba.conf for LDAP config?  Memory is failing, need more RAM!

Comment: > One option is to put the AuthLDAPBindPassword line in an appropriately chmodded file on its own, and use an Include in the apcahe config to pull that file in

I tried this and it didn't work.  The Apache manual says that the *Include* directive is only allowed within the main body, *Virtual Host*, or *Directory* directives; the example above uses a *Location* directive (e.g. a proxy) and the *Include* always generates an error when Apache reads the included file.

Answer (score 2):

some ldap servers allow anonymous binding. then [ afaik ] you dont need to provide bind password.

Comment: beside 15, cannot vote up but thanks a lot
Here, our ldap server does not allow anonymous binding

Answer (score 0):

Since Apache2 starts as root and reads config file before dropping root.

Assuming your current file config is owned by root and group is root, like so:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4K 2014-10-15 14:43 vhostconf`

You can just drop read/write/execute from the file to "other users":

`sudo chmod o-rwx /etc/apache2/sites-available/vhostconf`

You should end up with:

`-rw-r----- 1 root root 1.4K 2014-10-15 14:43 vhostconf`

This should be enough permissions for Apache2 to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Apache 2.2.25, AuthLDAPBindPassword can execute a command to find the password.

The simplest option would be to have

```
AuthLDAPBindPassword "exec:/bin/cat /some/file/with/password"
```

Details in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapbindpassword

Comment: When testing this on Apache/2.4.46 it worked fine in the beginning, but was accumulating defunct `cat` processes in the background until it suddenly stopped working. A restart of apache fixed it temporarily.
That's probably related to an apache issue reported in 2017: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61817